# Alarm Manager fail to setRepeating

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am having some problem with Alarm Manager in Android.

Inside the onCreate method:

```
        notificationCount = notificationCount + 1;
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                ReminderAlarm.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("NotifyCount", notificationCount);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                notificationCount, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                60000+System.currentTimeMillis(), pi);

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Reminder Alarm class:

```
public class ReminderAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private Notification notification;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent
            .getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);
    notification = new Notification(
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Notification",
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification
            .setLatestEventInfo(context, "AlarmActivated", "Hello", contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(
            Integer.parseInt(intent.getExtras()
                    .get("NotifyCount").toString()),
            notification); }}
```

In the boot receiver class:

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
    scheduleAlarms(context);
}

static void scheduleAlarms(Context context) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            60000+System.currentTimeMillis(),
                pi);
}
```

And in my manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 <receiver android:name=".ReminderAlarm" >
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I am trying to set the alarm to repeat every minute and prompt user notification. But it works in this way: when I launch the apps, it sets the alarm for once. After it prompt notification for once, then it stopped the repeating for every minute.

I wonder which part of my code went wrong. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

So basically I want the alarm manager to repeat everyday at 12am. Here is the codes:

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 );
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        notificationCount = notificationCount + 1;
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                ReminderAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                notificationCount, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

So by setting the repeating as such, will it still run after 44 years as previous one? or it will repeat everyday at 12am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter in the `setInexactRepeating()` method is the interval in milliseconds. You're setting that as the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.0 UTC plus 60000, making the next scheduled event about 44 years in the future. Change your code as follows:

```
mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 60000, pi);
```

Comment: 2 seconds faster than me :D

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks a lot! It works! But I wonder if I wanted to set it run once a day, I should replace the code as: mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi); ?

Comment: @MikeM.I couldn't believe it was as simple as that until I started to write an answer and...oh wait... :D

Comment: @MikeM. Okay sure thanks a lot! But I do have some question. Can you please help me take a look at the edited portion?

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry but would it run as what I've expected? or how should I fix that?

Comment: @MikeM. So can i assume that I just change the setInExact() to setExact() for my codes and it will run precisely at 12.01am?

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry, one last question. Let's say I am setting an alarm on 01/10/2014 4.47PM. With the codes from edited portion, will the alarm execute at 12.01AM on 02/10/2014?

Comment: Maybe. If you're in KitKat or above, repeating alarms are inexact, so it might not fire at that exact time. Per the docs, if you need exact repeating in API>18, use `setExact()` and set the alarm for the next day again every time it fires. Also, please post additional questions as questions. The mods are gonna start freaking if this comment chain gets any longer.

Comment: @MikeM. But again, it only trigger the alarm after the minute I've set it regardless on how long I set it to repeat and stopped the recurring. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @MikeM. Can you please help me take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102164/alarm-manager-not-running-in-background